# Redirect to a webpage using an if statement within an if statement in php, override meta html

Tags: php, html, redirect

I want to redirect to a webpage if a condition is met.

I'm already using meta to redirect if the condition is not met.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="4; url=form3.html" />

<?php

$to = "example@example.at"; 
$subject = "School Info";
$headers = "From: Free Project Day"; 
$field_school = $_POST['school'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$forward = "1";
$forward2 ="0";
$location = "index.html";


if (empty($field_school) || empty($field_email) && empty($field_tel) ) {
    echo 'Please correct the fields';
    return false;
    if ($forward == 1) {
        header ("Location:$location");
    }
}

$msg = "TEXT $date.\n\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";
}    

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
if ($forward2 == 1) {
    header ("Location:$location");
}
else {
    echo ("TEXT>");
}
?>
```

I tried to use the $forward but it did not work. Are the other ways to redirect without using Meta or $forward?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you returning false and then have a if sentence? - _also_ Why are you even using return false? I don't see a function. - There are many things wrong with this code, including the above stated I also don't see where you are setting the $field_tel?

Comment: I'ma  PHP noob, after fiddling with this code for a few hours this is as concise as I could get it. I thought the false refers to the mail function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this works according your posted codes. I made just few edits. Check if all conditions are as you intend as well

```
if ((empty($field_school) || empty($field_email)) && empty($field_tel) ) 
{
    echo 'Please correct the fields';
    //return false; No need for this as there's not function here
    if ($forward == 1) 
    {
        header('refresh:4;url='.$location);
        exit();
    }
}

$msg = "TEXT $date.\n\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
    $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n";
}    

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
if ($forward2 == 1) 
{
        header('refresh:4;url='.$location);
        exit();
}
else {
    echo "your messages here";
}
```

Comment: Hi, It worked at first but would not include the echos, as soon as echos are included it does not work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It will include the echos depending on your conditions. If conditions are met and within that section there's an echo then it will echo. All you need do to include them is something like. `if($forward == 1) { echo 'something'; header(.....);exit();}` Same applies when `forward == 2`. Edit your code and test

Answer (score 0):

After:

```
header ("Location:$location");
```

You need to add `exit();`

So, the code will be:

```
header ("Location:$location");
exit();
```

Comment: I pasted exit(); without adding anything in the brackets and it did not work. Should I add a URL in the brackets?

Comment: Check which condition is satisfied during runtime and then add exit() function or better you can add exit() function below every header function.

Comment: After a bit of fiddling it works perfectly. I needed to put the header before the echo and the exit() after both. Thanks!